# inserting multiple values against multiple ids in database table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form that takes **date**, **time in** and **time out** of all employees at once and submit it into the database table called attendance. the names of the employees are fetched from the database table and every employee has a unique id. 
 [image: here is my form table]
now the question is, how can i format the query that can insert the data into the database at once.  this is my php code.

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "employee_record";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$output="";
    $query= "SELECT * ";
    $query.= "FROM employe ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(!$result){
            echo ("Database query failed. ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    <form  action="test.php" method="POST" >
        <table border="1" style="margin-top: 20px">
            <thead>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time In</th>
                <th>Time Out</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?php   
        $id=array();
        $date=array();
        $timein=array();
        $timeout=array();
        while($employe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"";
                     echo $employe['id']; 
                    echo "\"/>";
                     echo $employe['firstname']." ".$employe['lastname']."</td>";
                     echo "<td><input type=\"date\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"\"/></td>";
                     echo "<td><input type=\"datetime-local\" name=\"timein[]\" value=\"\"/></td>";
                     echo "<td><input type=\"datetime-local\" name=\"timeout[]\" value=\"\"/></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
?>
```

Now say i have the data like..
id(1,2,3), 
date(date1,date2,date3),
timeIn(time1,time2,time3),
timeOut(time1,time2,time3).
 the amount of data varies becouse m fetching the ids from data table where number of employees can be more or less . now i'm just stuck on how can i insert this data against the ids in the database. 
any help will be appreciated..

Comment: It seems like all the dates would be the same ?!? But either way, there are tutorials for this sort of thing

Comment: How many rows are there likely to be for one form. I ask because inserting one row at  time will be simple to code. If you use prepared queries and transactions it will be reasonably quick. Approximate row count is all that is needed -  Tens, hundreds, thousands of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I understand the question correctly then perhaps something along these lines might help. This is, of course, untested with your data but I think the idea should work.

```
/*
    ------------------------------
    To process the form submission
    ------------------------------
*/

$update=false;/* change this if the final output sql looks correct..*/
$keys=array_keys( $_POST );
$length=count( $_POST[ $keys[ 0 ] ] );

for( $i=0; $i < $length; $i++ ){

    $params=array();

    foreach( $keys as $field ) {
        $value=$_POST[ $field ][ $i ];

        if( $field!=='id' ) $params[]="`{$field}`=\"".str_replace('"',"'",$value)."\"";
        else $where=" where `id`='".$value."';";
    }

    $sql="update `employee` set ".implode(', ',$params ) . $where;
    if( $update ) $result=mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
    else echo $sql.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: got it working with some changes in your method. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Update (2019)

After reviewing my original answer, I realized that I wouldn't use that method today. Basically because now I know, that executing one prepared statement row by row in single transaction is fast enough, unless we are talking about thousands of rows (which is unlikely the case when the data is user generated). Also any SQL injection protection was missing in the answer, which is now no issue with parameterized queries.

```php
$ids      = [];
$dates    = [];
$timeIns  = [];
$timeOuts = [];

// validate $_POST data and put into arrays above

$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE attendance SET
        date    = ?,
        tiemeIn = ?,
        timeOut = ?
    WHERE user_id = ?
");

$numRows = count($ids);

$conn->begin_transaction();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
        $stmt->bind_param('sssi', $date[$i], $timeIns[$i], $timeOuts, $ids[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
$conn->commit();
```

#### Original answer (2015)

To insert multiple (M) rows with N columns you can use the following syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename 
    (colname1, colname2, .. , colnameN) 
VALUES
    (valueRow1Colname1, valueRow1Colname2, .. , valueRow1ColnameN),
    (valueRow2Colname1, valueRow2Colname2, .. , valueRow2ColnameN),
    ..
    (valueRowMColname1, valueRowMColname2, .. , valueRowMColnameN);
```

You can create that query with PHP using function *join* or *implode*.

```php
$ids      = array();
$dates    = array(); 
$timeIns  = array();
$timeOuts = array();

// validate $_POST data and put into arrays above

$numInserts = count($ids);
if ($numInserts > 0) {
    $values = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numInserts; $i++) {
        $values[] = "({$ids[$i]}, '{$dates[$i]}', '{$timeIns[$i]}', '{$timeOuts[$i]}')";
    }
    $valuesJoined = join(',', $values);

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO attendance (user_id, date, tiemeIn, timeOut)
        VALUES {$valuesJoined}
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            date    = VALUES(date),
            tiemeIn = VALUES(tiemeIn),
            timeOut = VALUES(timeOut)
    ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Comment: i seems helpful but i want to do something like { "INSERT INTO attendance ( date, tiemeIn, timeOut) VALUES {$valuesJoined} WHERE user_id={multiple ids..}" }.
SO what will be the query then ??

Comment: It won't work the way you wrote. You could write `INSERT ... WHERE user_id IN (1, 5, 6)`, but you would insert same values for every user. But if the `user_id` is an unique or primary key, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for users that already have an entry.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

    print_r($_POST);// die;
                /*        Array
                (
                    [date] =2019-11-18
                    [id] = Array
                        (
                            [8] = 8
                            [9] = 9
                            [11] = 11
                            [14] = 14
                            [15] = 15
                            [17] = 17
                            [16] = 16
                        )

                    [a_status] = Array
                        (
                            [8] = present
                            [9] = present
                            [11] = present
                            [14] = present
                            [15] = present
                            [17] = present
                            [16] = present
                        )

                    [submit] = Submit
                )*/

    $i=0;
      $id =$_POST['id'];
      $a_status = $_POST['a_status'];
      $date = $_POST['date'];

      foreach ($a_status as $key => $id) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_attendance`(`stid`, `date`, `a_status`) VALUES('$key','".$_POST['date']."','$id')";
        echo $sql; //die;
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        // print_r($res);
        $i++;
      }
    //hi
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation?